# How to host a react, typescript website on aws lambda, nodejs 14.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda

I am trying to host a website on AWS lambda, the source is simple just showing hello world written in react and typeScript.

I used Webpack with babel-loader which build 2 files that is bundle.js and index.html

So I am trying to call the index.html in the lambda handler so that when I trigger lambda with API gateway, it will load index.html which will load bundle.js which is a script inside the index.html.

The code after build is bellow in screenshots.
The code for index.html

[image]

The code of handler in lambda.js

[image]

The picture of execution using test event

[image]

after opening the URL provided by the API gateway it shows
`{"message":"Internal Server Error"}`

I tried one more way that is by hard coding the index.html in the handler and then returning it but
it doesn't load the bundle.js may be it is not able to fetch it.

[image]

Execution response:
[image]

it shows the hello world written in the handler in

tag but not from the script
[image]

Please help me in fixing the problem,
Thank you guys.

I always fixed my problem using the stack overflow but now today I am here posting for the first time.